# Is there a way to catch start/stop event using pull-to-refresh gesture of ListView component?

Tags: react-native, react-native-listview

ListView component has "refreshControl" prop and using "RefreshControl" component we have "onRefresh" callback to know that user activates pull-to-refresh gesture...

But I cannot find something like "onPullStart" and "onPullEnd" event to know the moment of start/stop pull-to-refresh gesture.

[image]

Is there a way to catch these events?

Thanks.

Comment: There are 3 callbacks to control start/end scrolling content of ListView:  "onScroll", "onScrollEndDrag" and "onMomentumScrollEnd". BUT in Android, when user at the top of ListView and pulling down "onScroll" does't fired (because on Android actually content don't scrolling but on iOS do). So, the question is how to catch pull-up/down-to-refresh gesture...

Comment: Related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43800344/how-to-block-horizontal-gesture-in-parent-listview-in-react-native-on-android

Comment: did you find any solution for that

Comment: @SahirSaiyed nope

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Any update on this? @Stich